# Script file inclusion in Laravel 5.3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, laravel-5.3

How to include Script files like vue.js and app.js in Laravel 5.3 ? Is there any special way to include them ? I am including them like below.

```
<script src="http://127.0.0.1/addbook/node_modules/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the other answer, you should read through `Laravel elixir`'s doc first, with it we can simply write 5 lines of config and get a smooth front-end developing experience right away, which includes `webpack` for asset packaging, `babel` for transpiling ES6 code to ES5, and `browser-sync` for file watching and multi-device-synced browser auto refresh.

On top of elixir, here's some practices I follow:

- Include a generic `app.js` in your `layouts/app.blade.php`, which includes the codes you are *absolutely* sure you want in your every page. e.g. I put `$('.datetime').datetimepicker(...)` in it so the `bootstrap` datetime picker plugin inits the pickers for me wherever I put `.datetime` in html.
- For those libraries you import with npm, `import` them in the specific view's js file so that webpack will compile your code with the library you inlcuded. You can either `Vue = require('vue');` or `import Vue from 'vue';`, the latter is not supported by `node.js` or any browser but babel transpiles it for us.
- Now you have a specific view, say, `login.blade.php`, which `@extends` the `app.blade.php` layout. Also we know that the best practice is to put the script files at the bottom of html's `body` so they don't block dom parsing and resource downloading. I personally use `Laravel blade`'s syntax in `login.blade.php` like

---

```
@push('childJS')
<script src='/js/login.js'></script>
@endpush
```

and in `app.blade.php`:

```
    <script src='/js/app.js'></script>
    @stack('childJS')
</body>
```

so the 2 js files both appear at the bottom of `body` to get best performance and `app.js` always appear before `login.js` so that depencies between js files are resolved well.

Comment: Thanks @PanJunjie for your details Answer. Actually I am new in `vue.js` development and I am not so familiar with `node_modules`. That's why I don't know the responsibilities of  `webpack`, `babel`, `transpiling ES6 code to ES5` and `browser-sync` but I heard about them.  
Actually my intention was to attract your attention to adding `vue.js` in Laravel. You can see the `vue.js` is in inside `node_modules` folder. Should I copy `vue.js` file inside `js` folder of `resource` folder to include it in my application?  
Is there any way include them automatically with the help of `node_modules`?

Comment: @abuabu As stated in the answer, you can `import` or `require` the library and after compilation the import statement will go away and your own code and libraries(from `node_modules`) will be bundled together. If you feel it's too compicated, you can surely just copy the js file to your `assets/js` folder and include it with a script tag like we always do.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [asset](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-asset) for this or even better [elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/helpers#method-elixir) and you should rather don't put node_modules into your public directory just copy files you want to use via [Laravel elixir](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/elixir#introduction)